# Access list elements in plain text using r

Tags: r, list, syntax

I am using R markdown and i am trying to knit to PDF.

I have list "la" looking like this:

```
dput(la)
list(0.477543511334121, 0.288569304013141, 0.790270489777863)
```

I want to create a table using:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
 age & la[1] & la[2] & la[3]] \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However i would like la[[1]], la[[2]] etc. to give me the corresponding list elements rather than having it written in plain text.

I am thankfull for help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset; possibly `dput(la)` if it is not too big. Also could you provide some context for the use of LaTeX: are you working in a `Rmarkdown` pdf document?

Comment: Maybe `unlist` it first?

Comment: @NelsonGon Same result.